# AccessLevel cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have made the following class in java spring

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;

@Embeddable
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force=true,access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
public class BusinessPeriod {
    LocalDate startDate;
    LocalDate endDate;
}
```

Unfortunately, in the line     `@NoArgsConstructor(force=true,access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`, it complains that

```
AccessLevel cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you forgot to:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
```